# Incompatible argument to function camelContext with spring xml

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

Hi excuse me for my small knowledge but I am a beginner in using spring and camel. I am trying to make a simple camelContext bean that routes a message from an endpoint to another spring bean called smartlighting. The problem is whenever I initialize the camelContext even empty one in the xml i get this weird "Incompatible argument to function" exception.

I am using spring 3.0 & camel 2.10.3 & tomcat server v7.0

My spring xml is as shown:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
    "> 

<camelContext id="camelcontext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<route streamCache="true">
   <from uri="jetty:http://192.168.1.99:1989/sample/endpoint"/>
   <bean ref="smartlighting" method="test"/>
</route>   
</camelContext>


<bean id="smartlighting" class="com.example.smartlighting.SmartLightingApp" init-method="init"/>

</beans>
```

and i get this exception whenever i run the project

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/apache/camel/spring/CamelContextFactoryBean, method: initThreadPoolProfiles signature: (Lorg/apache/camel/CamelContext;)V) Incompatible argument to function
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:458)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:388)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:261)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:192)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5204)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5199)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make camel namespace as default namespace in your context file and refer spring beans using beans aliasname.
Eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">


<beans:bean id="smartlighting" class="com.example.smartlighting.SmartLightingApp" init-method="init"/>



<camelContext id="camelcontext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

<route streamCache="true">

   <from uri="{{your}}"/>

   <bean ref="smartlighting" method="test"/>

</route>   

</camelContext>

</beans:beans>
```